# display echo data in listview Android

Tags: php, android, android-listview, httpclient

So, my php file echo a list of data separated by \n format now when I try to display it in list view, it consider the entire content as a single list item in android. How do I tell my listadapter to consider a new element at xx position as there is no loop in my android code.

```
<?php 
$query="SELECT * FROM `safa_offers` ORDER BY id DESC ";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());



while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

                                        {
    echo  "Offer Name\n".$row['offer_name']. " \n \n "."Start Date :\n".$row['offer_start']."\n \n"."End Date \n".$row['offer_end']."\n \n"."Details: \n".$row['offer_description']."\n\n";
                                        }

 mysql_close($cn);
 exit();

 ?>
```

Android:

```
void login(){
    try{            

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://agfsrg/Offers.php");
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

        //This is the response from a php application
        final String reverseString = response;
        //offers.setText(reverseString);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "response" + reverseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //offers.setText(reverseString);
                listAdapter.add( reverseString );
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just split the string on the newline character? You can just use the asList funtion from the array class since split returns an array. See here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...). Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Worked Excellently, used split() method and converted the string into array and then filled my list with listAdapter.addAll( Arrays.asList(items) ); Thankyou for guiding :)